# How to replace character string within a string with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a long string which contains tag `img` and attribute `src`,but now I want to delete some strings in `src` with Regular Expression.

I had tried as following codes, but I think there is some error in `pattern`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#encoding: utf-8
import re
url = "<p><img src ='https://xxx.cn/20190504195124718.png?x-oss-process=image/watermark,type_ZmFuZ3poZW5naGVpdGk,shadow_10,text_aHR0cHM6Ly9ibG9nLmNzZG4ubmV0L2gzNTYzNjM=,size_16,color_FFFFFF,t_70'></img></p><p><img src ='https://xxxx.cn/20190504195124718.png?x-oss-process=image/watermark,type_ZmFuZ3poZW5naGVpdGk,shadow_10,text_aHR0cHM6Ly9ibG9nLmNzZG4ubmV0L2gzNTYzNjM=,size_16,color_FFFFFF,t_70'></img></p>"

pattern = re.compile(r"https://img-.*(\?x-oss-process.*t_70)")

print(pattern.findall(url))

out = re.sub(pattern, '', url)

print(out)
```

The first print,get the result:

```
['?x-oss-process=image/watermark,type_ZmFuZ3poZW5naGVpdGk,shadow_10,text_aHR0cHM6Ly9ibG9nLmNzZG4ubmV0L2gzNTYzNjM=,size_16,color_FFFFFF,t_70']
```

The second print ,get the result:

```
<p><img src =''></img></p>
```

I want to get the new string which `img` `src` delete the string`?x-oss-process=image/watermark,type_ZmFuZ3poZW5naGVpdGk,shadow_10,text_aHR0cHM6Ly9ibG9nLmNzZG4ubmV0L2gzNTYzNjM=,size_16,color_FFFFFF,t_70`,only have the "https://xxx.cn/20190504195124718.png".

Just like:

```
url = "<p><img src ='https://xxx.cn/20190504195124718.png'></img></p><p><img src ='https://xxxx.cn/20190504195124718.png'></img></p>"
```

How to write the `pattern`?

Thanks so much~

Comment: Do u want to use regex or you can do with some other method?

Comment: What's the other method? Could you talk about it in detail? Thanks.

Comment: check my answer below.

Comment: `pattern = re.compile(r"(https://img-.*)(\?x-oss-process.*t_70)")` then  `match =pattern.match(url)` and extract it as`match.group(0)`

Comment: See my updated answer with substitution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to substitute the string we will be using a capturing group 
`(?#...)`

```
output = re.sub("(?#<img.*)\?x-oss-process.*?t_70",'',url)
```

Added ? before `t_70` for non greedy matching which will capture multiple `img` tags.

From docs

> (?#...)
>       A comment; the contents of the parentheses are simply ignored.

See docs [here] (https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Comment: Unfortunately，with your codes , I got an error ```AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'```, how to fix it?

Comment: @SylorHuang I have added fix for multiple capture and substitution for your string

Answer (score 0):

**Edited to add second img also**

I find regex a bit complicated for certain scenarios, Python is full power house. So for the above case, I will use the following code:-

```
url = "<p><img src ='https://xxx.cn/20190504195124718.png?x-oss-process=image/watermark,type_ZmFuZ3poZW5naGVpdGk,shadow_10,text_aHR0cHM6Ly9ibG9nLmNzZG4ubmV0L2gzNTYzNjM=,size_16,color_FFFFFF,t_70'></img></p><img src ='https://xxxx.cn/20190504195124718.png?x-oss-process=image/watermark,type_ZmFuZ3poZW5naGVpdGk,shadow_10,text_aHR0cHM6Ly9ibG9nLmNzZG4ubmV0L2gzNTYzNjM=,size_16,color_FFFFFF,t_70'></img></p>"

new_url = url.split('?')[0] +"></img><img" + url.split('?')[1].split('<img')[-1] +"\'</img></p>"

print(new_url)
```

It will split the url at "?", we will take the first item and then add the remaining html to it. Hope it helps. Peace!!!

Comment: With your codes , I get the result ```<p><img src ='https://img-blog.csdnimg.cn/20190504195124718.png'></img></p>"```,it just return the first ```img```,not the both two ```img```.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I didn't notice the second image. In that case I think using regex will be better.

Comment: Could you give me some proposal ？ I don't know much about regular expressions. Thanks.

Comment: Yes ,as your codes , I could get two new ```src```, but the new problem is that maybe the ```url``` has more than two ```img```, at this time , I think your codes maybe not very suitable. As you say, regex will be better. So is there any method with regex? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use beautiful for this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "<p><img src ='https://xxx.cn/20190504195124718.png?x-oss-process=image/watermark,type_ZmFuZ3poZW5naGVpdGk,shadow_10,text_aHR0cHM6Ly9ibG9nLmNzZG4ubmV0L2gzNTYzNjM=,size_16,color_FFFFFF,t_70'></img></p><p><img src ='https://xxxx.cn/20190504195124718.png?x-oss-process=image/watermark,type_ZmFuZ3poZW5naGVpdGk,shadow_10,text_aHR0cHM6Ly9ibG9nLmNzZG4ubmV0L2gzNTYzNjM=,size_16,color_FFFFFF,t_70'></img></p>"

#Parse the html
soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')

#Get all img tags
li = [tag.attrs['src'] for tag in soup.find_all() if tag.name == 'img']

#Iterate through tags and replace urls
for item in li:
  original_src = item
  new_src = item.split('?')[0]
  url = url.replace(original_src, new_src)

print(url)
```

The output will be

```
<p><img src ='https://xxx.cn/20190504195124718.png'></img></p>
<p><img src ='https://xxxx.cn/20190504195124718.png'></img></p>
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm not clearly described my question, I'm not want to get the ```img``` src value, but I just want to rewrite the ```src``` . Thanks~

Comment: Updated my code to fix that @SylorHuang Please check and let me know if it works :)